# How to scrape newspaper articles from multiple newspaper websites with help of RSS feeds

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, rss

I have to do some Data Collection that is obtain a obtain a large stream relatively clean corpus. The corpus is simply a collection of webpages (HTML) - each page corresponding to a news article with associated information such as the date of its publication, edition it appears in, the section in which it appears etc.

I have to develop a crawler that can crawl news paper websites of different languages in parallel.
Let us identify 2 languages (English and Hindi). Write a crawler to scrape articles from the website of these newspapers. We have to collect it for 1 month

What we are interested is in collecting a large number of multiple language news articles from the websites of various newspapers as they are published on their website.

Instead of writing a full-fledged scraper, I have been told to use sources like RSS feeds.
The idea is to obtain parallel corpora - i.e., newspaper articles that are in different languages and in sync with each other.

After building crawler, we have to set it up on a server to obtain the newspaper stream

Please let me which tools and programming language should I use to build this crawler.
I know JAVA, so I would want to preferably work on Java libraries.
I know that RSS feeds are in XML

Comment: I'd say: use Java, read up on the RSS spec, and go from there. I'm not sure what else anyone can help with here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is the question, but yes, RSS feeds are probably the way to go (at least as a signal) and yes, JAVA has great tools to deal with feeds :)

Comment: Please specify the Java tools..my problem is that I have to parse the RSS pages. Example: http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss Also RSS feed only provide excerpts, not the whole news article. I want the full article along with publication date, edition, section etc.

Comment: There are literaly dozens of tools. This article can help : http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/ And for full article, that's what I meant by using RSS as a signal: one you identify a new entry, you can still fetch the page corresponding to it.

Comment: Hi Julien, Appreciate your reply, "what do u mean by RSS as a signal". Which page are you asking me to fetch? Is it the source XML page or the article page which is in HTML. The RSS page contain only snippets of news, not the full detailed article. Basically I have to create a clean corpus which is a collection of webpages (HTML) - each page corresponding to an article with associated information such as the date of its publication, edition it appears in, the section in which it appears etc.

Comment: Well, I think you need to read and learn more about what you're trying to build :) I can't answer these questions without being sarcastic! Once you understand what you're dealing with, all the answers will come by themselves.